# Browser crashes on auto-scroll puppeteer

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, windows-11

I have a scraper that scrapes the video urls of all the posts of a user. I have implemented auto-scroll so that all the videos are loaded for me to scrape. I tested it out on my laptop (MacOS) and a desktop PC (Windows 10) and it was working perfectly. I made a zip file of it and sent it to a friend to check it out. And weirdly enough, it wasn't working for him (Windows 11)!
Whenever puppeteer tries to scroll the page, the browser gets a message at the top saying "Something went wrong" and it closes.
Here is the code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const createCsvWriter = require('csv-writer').createObjectCsvWriter;
const Spinner = require('cli-spinner').Spinner;
const { exit } = require('process');

const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
  path: 'data.csv',
  header: [
    { id: 'id', title: '#' },
    { id: 'URL', title: 'URL' },
  ],
});

(async function main() {
  var spinner = new Spinner('Scraping data.... %s');
  spinner.setSpinnerString('|Oo-\\');
  spinner.start();

  let data = [];
  let counter = 1;

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.setUserAgent(
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36'
  );
  await page.goto(`https://www.tiktok.com/@${process.argv[2]}`, {
    waitUntil: 'load',
    timeout: 0,
  });
  await page.waitForSelector('.tiktok-yz6ijl-DivWrapper > a');
  await page.waitForSelector('.tiktok-yz6ijl-DivWrapper > a');

  let lastHeight = await page.evaluate('document.body.scrollHeight');

  while (true) {
    await page.evaluate('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)');
    await page.waitForTimeout(2000);
    let newHeight = await page.evaluate('document.body.scrollHeight');
    if (newHeight === lastHeight) {
      break;
    }
    lastHeight = newHeight;
  }

  let values = await page.evaluate((sel) => {
    let elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(sel));
    let responses = elements.map((element) => {
      return element.getAttribute('href');
    });
    return responses;
  }, '.tiktok-yz6ijl-DivWrapper > a');

  values.map((value) => {
    data.push({
      id: counter,
      URL: value,
    });
    counter++;
  });

  csvWriter.writeRecords(data).then(() => {
    console.log('...Done');
    exit(0);
  });
})();
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Ane errors in the console while the browser crashes?

Comment: @Vaviloff Nope. Nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. As I understand it, Tiktok somehow determined that a bot was coming in, and not a person, and did not load the video further, because when I tried to scroll manually, I received the same error. I was helped by the use of puppeteer stealth:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");
const StealthPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth");
const createCsvWriter = require("csv-writer").createObjectCsvWriter;
const Spinner = require("cli-spinner").Spinner;
const { exit } = require("process");

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

//below is your code without changes
```